# R Script to generate random dataset in 2d space

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, clustering

I want to analyze the effectiveness and efficiency of kernel methods for which I would require 3 different data-set in 2 dimensional space for each of the following cases:

1. BAD_kmeans: The data set for which the kmeans clustering algorithm
   will not perform well.
2. BAD_pca: The data set for which the Principal Component Analysis
   (PCA) dimension reduction method upon projection of the original
   points into 1-dimensional space (i.e., the first eigenvector) will
   not perform well.
3. BAD_svm: The data set for which the linear Support Vector Machine
   (SVM) supervised classification method using two classes of points
   (positive and negative)  will not perform well.

Which packages can I use in R to generate the random 2d data-set for each of the above cases ? A sample script in R would help in understanding

Comment: Can you clarify what these data sets are that you are trying to generate? what have you tried in R so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the algorithms you mention are good with data that has uniform distribution.

```
size <- 20             #length of random number vectors
set.seed(1) 
x <- runif(size)          # generate samples from uniform distribution (0.0, 1.0)
y <-runif(size) 
df <-data.frame(x,y)

# other distributions: rpois, rmvnorm, rnbinom, rbinom, rbeta, rchisq, rexp, rgamma, rlogis, rstab, rt, rgeom, rhyper, rwilcox, rweibull.
```

See [this page](http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/prob_dist.htm) for tutorial on generating random samples from distributions.

---

For specific set of randomized data sets that are 'hard' for these methods (e.r. linearly inseparable *n*-classes XOR patterns), see this blog post (incl. R code): http://tjo-en.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/06/234155.

Comment: How can I generate a confusion matrix for the above mentioned input data to check various Performance measures such as variance, precision, recall, F1 measure ?

Comment: I do know that I can use the function confusionMatrix(predicted, actual) of the caret package, the only problem I am facing is with the predicted values. Since the data generated is ambiguous, I am not able to understand what the predicted values should be ?

Comment: In the worst case (uniform distribution), there is no "predicted value" because there are no clusters in the data. For data generated by other algorithms (e.g. linearly inseparable n-classes XOR), the algorithm does generate *n* classes, so they would be the basis for comparing predicted (i.e. perfect classification) vs actual (what ever your ML method yields)

Comment: I did get the clusters using the above dataset through kmeans. Hence I wished to find the performance metrics so that after running kernel tricks, I can compare the performance metrics before and after applying kernel tricks

Comment: One more thing I noticed is that, the SSE generated using kmeans lies between 0.2 and 0.35, which makes me wonder whether the dataset can actually be considered 'bad' for kmeans?

Comment: Any given realization of a random data set could yield good clustering. But if you run it many times, as you should for statistical testing, and you'll find that it fails as often as it succeeds.